# xslt transform (json to csv)

Tags: json, xslt

I'm trying to convert json to csv using xslt.

Here is my XSLT style sheet.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">
    
  <xsl:param name="json-string" as="xs:string">[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "manu"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "vivek"
    }
]</xsl:param>

  <xsl:param name="json-xml" select="json-to-xml($json-string)"/>

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
    <xsl:value-of select="$json-xml/*/*!string-join(*, ',')" separator="&#10;"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When the data itself has comma means that particular data should enclosed inside the double quotes.

Example:-

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "ma,nu"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "vivek"
    }
]
```

Current output:-

```
1,ma,nu
2,vivek
```

Excepted output:-

```
1,"ma,nu"
2,vivek
```

How to modify the above xslt?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `string-join(*, ',')` by `string-join(*!f:escape(.), ',')` and write a function

```
<xsl:function name="f:escape" as="xs:string" expand-text="yes">
  <xsl:param name="in" as="xs:string"/>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains($in, ',')">"{$in}"</xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>{$in}</xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:function>
```

(But what if the value also contains quotes? At this point, dialects of CSV start to do their own thing...)